# Bootstrap 3 navbar links display vertical when should be horizontal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, railstutorial.org

Following Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial and after importing bootstrap into a custom.css.scss file the links display as a block (vertical) when they should really be horizontal causing the navbar to be really thick as shown below. So the question is what did I do wrong and how can I make the navigation horizontal using boostrap?

[image]

Here's my application.html.erb layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <%= link_to "Dog Park", root_path, id: "logo" %>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
                            <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
                            <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
                            <li><%= link_to "Play Time", '#' %></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here's my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.0.3.0"

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: Either you or something else could be overriding the css methods. If so the you can override the methods yourself, you can find out if they're overridden in your browsers debugger. Just having a quick look at bootstrap, perhaps try to add `navbar-right` as a class to `ul`. Give it go and tell me.

Comment: This happens because you are using bootstrap-sass-3, the [tutorial Gemfile](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#code-bcrypt_ruby) forces the use of bootstrap-sass-2 with `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'`

Answer (score 7):

(I don't have enough rep to comment on Mlennie's answer, so this needs to be a separate answer)

As Mlennie says, "adding a navbar-nav class finally worked."

What this means is to change:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
```

To:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding a navbar-nav class finally worked.