# Rails Bootstrap vertically - Resetting Assets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

My rails _header has a bug in it. The nav pull-right elements are stacking vertically instead of horizontally. How would I fix this?

[image]

when it should be

[image]

I have very basic style sheets that haven't changed pull-right.

thanks

Comment: Put them in an inline block perhaps? Can we see the code? Github repo perhaps?

Comment: do you have a scaffold.css?

Comment: Yep, here it is: https://github.com/MarcusHSmith/BattleOfTheBands/tree/master/app/assets/stylesheets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961127/bootstrap-3-navbar-links-display-vertical-when-should-be-horizontal

Solved it right away