# Michael Hartl RoR tutorial, navigation bar chapter 5 not aligning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to go through Michael Hartl's (brilliant) Ruby on Rails tutorial, but I have a problem in chapter 5.  The navigation bar in the header aligns vertically and aligns to the left, and not horizontally and to the right.

My header (**_header.html.erb**) looks like this:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",   '#' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help",   '#' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

and in the **Gemfile** I have

```
gem 'rails',                       '5.0.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',              '3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails',                  '5.0.6'
```

The questions been asked before (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961127/bootstrap-3-navbar-links-display-vertical-when-should-be-horizontal)) but those were with older versions of RoR and of no help to me.  Anyone got an idea?

[EDIT]

The **application.css** file in app/assets/stylesheets contains the lines:

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

and the **custom.scss** file in the same folder starts with:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: is has nothing to do with rails itself. it is just about twitter-bootstrap and how you use it

Comment: No, I understand it's something to do with the style sheets and not with R or RoR, but it's in the RoR tutorial, and I can't find the solution, and I really don't wanna spend hours digging into Bootstrap while I really wanna do the RoR tutorial ;)

Comment: can you confirm that you've required `bootstrap` in your `assets/stylesheets/application.[css|scss]`

Comment: I have edited my original post and have added the application.css and the custom.scss files.  My page does show all kinds of other styles I haven't defined and which I assume come from bootstrap, it's just the alignment of the top navigation that is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: I had my browser width at 760px as I had a split screen with the Developer Tools on the right.  When I made my window wider the navigation bar aligned properly.  Hiding in shame now ;)